# Postgresql Auto backup script runs in terminal but does not runs in CRON job

Tags: postgresql, cron, backup

I used Common Postgresql backup script from [Automated_Backup_on_Linux](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux)

It runs in the terminal

```
vijay@HCL:~/backups$ bash pg_backup.sh
```

But does not run when in CRONTAB in Ubuntu 12.04

```
*/1 * * * * /home/vijay/backups/pg_backup.sh
```

Not even logs error in /var/log/syslog

Comment: I also did '$service cron restart' immediately after editing crontab -e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the difference between your two commands you are running it in a different way, the first is being run from within the directory, the second is being run from the full path. My suggested next options would be;

1. Run the script with the full path from your command line and see if any errors are generated and then resolve those errors.

OR

2. Change the cron job to read like the following `*/1 * * * * cd /home/vijay/backups; bash pg_backup.sh`.

Also, are you sure this script needs to be run every minute?

Comment: Awesome!.Second Option Worked,first option din't do any thing.

Answer (score 0):

Befor trying **Dayvo's** Awesome Option I tried

I Made backup.sh file (executable + Read and write) in ubuntu 12 which also worked.